# What is the difference between the $get and $find functions?

Tags: javascript, function, asp.net-ajax

What is the difference between the $get and $find functions in javascript?

I'm guessing that these functions aren't really javascript-native things, so an additional question would be what *are* they native to?

**Clarification**

The web app I've seen this in uses jquery and ASP.NET AJAX. Perhaps that changes the meaning of these functions?

Comment: $get and $find in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about the [MS Ajax Client Library](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/default.aspx) shortcut methods.

[`$find`](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/FindShortcutMethod.aspx) is a shortcut for the [`Sys.Application.findComponent`](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationFindComponentMethod.aspx) method, and allows you to get a [Component](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys/ComponentClass/default.aspx) object.

[$get](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortcutMethod.aspx) is a shortcut for the [Sys.UI.DomElement getElementById](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys.UI/DomElementClass/SysUIDomElementGetElementByIdMethod.aspx) method, and it returns a [DomElement](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys.UI/DomElementClass/default.aspx) object.

Check the following article:

- [The Ever-Useful $get and $find ASP.NET AJAX Shortcut Functions](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html)

Answer (score 0):

$get and $find are not part of Javascript. They are either a part of your Javascript host, in any library or code you have or undefined. If they are undefined then there is no difference.